# Unable to locate an element within iframe using ember through Selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, capybara

I'm doing automation using cucumber (My first time doing automation). The UI is in iFrame & using ember. (UI code is from another team, therefore, any change on UI is not applicable)

I'm trying to find the text field & fill in the field (the last piece). However, I keep getting element not found. Anyone can help to suggest any method to find it ?

**HTML Code**

```
  <div id="payeePassportNumber" class="form-row-line">
        <div id="ember866" class="rdc-component-base rdc-text-input rdc-text-input no-label label-top ember-view">  
            <div class="label-holder">
                <label>Passport Number</label><!---->
            </div>
            <div class="component-holder">
                <div class="component-wrapper textinput-wrapper">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="" maxlength="140" id="ember867" class="ember-text-field ember-view">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Ruby Code before question was anwsered**

```
session.within_frame(session.find(:xpath, "//[@id='myframe']")) do
    session.driver.browser.find_element(:id, 'payeeDetails').click
    if payeeDetails == 'Passport Number'
    session.find(:xpath,"//[text()[normalize-space()='#{payeeDetails}']]").click
    session.driver.browser.find_element(:id, 'payeePassportCountry').click
    session.find(:xpath,"//[text()[normalize-space()='#{country}']]").click
    session.fill_in session.find(:xpath, "//[@id='payeePassportNumber']/div/div[2]/div[contains(@Class, 'component-wrapper textinput-wrapper')]"), :with => "123456"
```

**Error**

```
 invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //[@id='payeePassportNumber']///div/[contains(@Class, 'component-wrapper textinput-wrapper')] because of the following error:
    SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//[@id='payeePassportNumber']///div/[contains(@Class, 'component-wrapper textinput-wrapper')]' is not a valid XPath expression.
    (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSelectorError)
```

**Ruby Code after question was anwsered**

```
session.within_frame('myframe') do
        #find proxy type dropdown list & select proxy type
        session.find('#payeeDetails').click
        session.find("li", text: "#{payeeDetails}").click       
            if payeeDetails == 'Passport Number'

                #find country dropdownlist & select country
                session.find('#payeePassportCountry').click
                session.find(:xpath,"//*[text()[normalize-space()='#
                {country}']]").click
                #fills in proxy ID
                session.find('#payeePassportNumber').fill_in with: proxyID
            end
end
```

Comment: @Sers Perhaps I still didn't understand the objective of your edit where you removed the [tag:CssSelector] _tag_ but your answer still continues to suggest a CssSelector.

Comment: @DebanjanB I replaced css selector with capybara because of the tag limitation and capybara was more relevant, but the problem resolved.

Comment: @Sers See how your edit vandalized the post. You removed the tag [tag:css-selectors] to add the tag [tag:capybara] but you didn't remove the [tag:webdriverwait]. Please take care during your edits else OP will never receive canonical and working answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a number of things wrong with your code:

1. You're calling find where you don't need to.
2. You're calling direct driver methods (anytime you're using `.driver.browser` you're probably doing something wrong).
3. You're passing elements to methods that don't take elements (`fill_in`),
4. Doing complex xpath queries with normalize-space is generally never the right approach.

Without seeing all the HTML your code is referring to (#payeeDetails, which elements you're trying to click with your `normalize-space` xpaths, etc) it's hard to give full fixes for your code but the simplest way to fill in the input field shown in your HTML (assuming it's in an iframe with id of 'myframe') would be something like

```
session.within_frame('myframe') do
  session.find('#payeePassportNumber').fill_in with: '123456'
end
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't address OP's main error i.e. _invalid selector_

Comment: @DebanjanB Correct, it answers the OPs question which is "I'm trying to find the text field & fill in the field (the last piece)...... Anyone can help to suggest any method to find it ?" - which is exactly what my answer does.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole
1. session.within_frame('myframe') -> this won't do, I already used it and it cannot find the iframe. I'm myself not sure why. Therefore, i put in the find xpath  
2. I'm really new to coding, those with driver.browser -> i use it due to whenever i tried to use find xpath or find css, i won't be able to find the element.  
3. Ahh i see.. will take not on this.  
4. I found the code while doing some research hehe, and able to find the element that way.

Comment: @yanayeay It will if you're using a newish version of Capybara - I'm guessing you're still on 2.x ??

Comment: @ThomasWalpole capybara (3.14.0) -> my capybara version

Comment: @yanayeay hmmm -- maybe there's a bug then.. It definitely should work like that if your iframe has an id of `myframe` - you weren't passing `#myframe` were you??  It defaults to the :frame selector type - not a CSS selector.  If you did want to use css or xpath you could do `session.within_frame(:css, '#myframe') do`

Comment: @ThomasWalpole nope, i used this exact same code `session.within_frame('myframe')` , not sure if using ember (the HTML code is using ember) if will behaving differently ? I still have so much to learn. From all the comments i'm learning something new.

Comment: @yanayeay 2. Without knowing what code you had before it's impossible to say why it wasn't finding what you wanted, but dropping to `.driver.browser` is never really a good idea, especially as a beginner.  4. Without knowing which elements exactly you were trying to find I can't give a replacement, but you probably want to be using the `text` option that find takes along with a selector that chooses an element type instead.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Anyway, i have use this to fill in `session.find('#payeePassportNumber').fill_in with: '123456'` & it's a success! oh my god. i've been working for 2 days for this thing.

Comment: @yanayeay Great to hear -- that works because there's only one fillable field inside the payeePassportNumber div so `fill_in` will assume that's the one you want it to fill in.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I see, will take note on that. Thanks a zillion !

Comment: @yanayeay You're welcome. If you could provide the HTML for your iframe element (possibly file an issue on the Capybara github) I would like to figure out why the `within_frame` with id isn't working for you because I can't replicate that failure and it's something specifically tested for in Capybaras test suite.  The only reason I can come up with is if you were already inside a `within` block that didn't contain the iframe element, but your code in the question doesn't show that.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole silly me.. i didn't put any quote when i used
`session.within_frame('myframe')` I have now replace the code.. and it's working fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your error tells you what is wrong:

```
"//[@id='payeePassportNumber']/div/div[2]/div[contains(@Class, 'component-wrapper textinput-wrapper')]"
```

is not a valid XPath expression.

I suspect that @Class is confused by the space in the class name.  Try the following xpath:

```
"//div[@id='payeePassportNumber']/div/div[2]/div[contains(@class, 'component-wrapper') and  contains(@class, 'textinput-wrapper')]"
```

Does that help?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but im getting the same error as others.. it says unable to find the field.. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `@Class` with capital C, and overall your selector is wrong.
Try to use simple selectors like below:

1. css selector: `#payeePassportNumber input`
2. xpath: `//div[@id='payeePassportNumber']//input`

Comment: Nice.  Much better than my attempt at patching the user's xpath.

Comment: ohmygod... i didn't realize the capital c.. thanks for highlighting this.. i have tried using this //div[@id='payeePassportNumber']//input before, but it's still below error
ElementNotFound : Unable to find field #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="input" path="/HTML/BODY[1]/DIV[2]/DIV[1]/DIV[5]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[3]/DIV[1]/DIV[2]/DIV[1]/INPUT[1]">

Comment: @yanayeay try with wait and check if there’s any iframe

Comment: i have put in sleep 5, but still getting the unable to find field.. 
and i have check.. only have one iframe... T_T

Comment: @yanayeay please check how to correct switch to iframe with Capybara [here](https://makandracards.com/makandra/34015-use-capybara-commands-inside-an-iframe)

Comment: @Sers do i need to switch again ? as i already switch to iframe. 
i have few other steps, which need to select country. i'm already able to click & select the country, and next step is to fill in the text field (it's within the same iframe).. which im unable to..

Comment: @yanayeay don’t need

Comment: @Sers if the html code, having the value of placeholder, would that be easier ?